# Converting JSON 64bit string to an Image - difficulty

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, core-data, cloudkit

My project accesses a JSON file with 200+ country elements of which one name/value pair is flag: containing what I think is Base64 encryption - example below.  I have successfully included the name: and the :flag in a Picker.  The Picker works fine and displays the chosen country and update the CoreData & CloudKit (ClientEntity) record with both. The challenge is to call the record for display or editing. I cannot get the flag Image to display - only the default value. It is storing something in the clientFlag field. I was expecting it to store the flag:1920 bytes of JSON data - instead (copied from the console) it is storing "CD_clientFlag" = "{ length=1458, sha256=c1572719d906e1df50fdf296845b0942ef148060c609d585434777b6276a67e9 }";\n

Clearly, my logic is faulty or this field contains a different data format, or both. Any help would be appreciated.
Of course a better method would be to reference the JSON data via the id: or the name:, but I gave up on this due to inexperience and opted to store both name: and flag

Relevant code below:

**Successful Picker code in a View**

```
NavigationStack {
            Form {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    clientNameAddress
                    Group {
                                Picker(selection: $selectedCountry,
                                       label: Text("")) {
                                    ForEach(countryVM.countries) { country in
                                        HStack {
                                            Text(country.name)
                                            if let flagImage = country.flagImage {
                                                Image(uiImage: flagImage)
                                            } else {
                                                Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                                            }
                                        }.tag(country as Country?)//: HSTACK6
                                    }
                                }
                                       .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                                       .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        VStack {
                            Text("Selected Country: \(selectedCountry?.name ?? "No Name")")
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            if let flagImage = selectedCountry?.flagImage {
                                Image(uiImage: flagImage)
                            }
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        }
                    Toggle("Existing Client?", isOn: $clientVM.clientExisting)
                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
//                    SelectContact()
                    Button(action: {
                        assignFlag()
                        print("AddView \(clientVM.clientHostCountry)")
                        clientVM.addClient(context: viewContext)
                        dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        if clientVM.clientItem == nil {
                            Text("Add Account")
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 200)
                        } else {
                            Text("Save Modified Client")
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 200)
                        }
                    })
                    .tint(.purple)
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle)
                }
                .navigationTitle(clientVM.clientItem == nil ? "Add Account" : "Edit Account \(clientVM.clientName)")
            }.disableAutocorrection(true)
            #if os(iOS)
                .navigationBarTitle("Add Account")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            #endif
        }
```

**JSON Example**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Albania",
    "isoAlpha2": "AL",
    "isoAlpha3": "ALB",
    "isoNumeric": 8,
    "currency": {
        "code": "ALL",
        "name": "Lek",
        "symbol": "Lek"
    },
    "flag": "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"
}
```

**CountryViewModel**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Country: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable, Hashable {

    let id = UUID() // New
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: Data?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, isoAlpha3, flag
    }

    var flagImage: UIImage? {
        guard let flagData = flag else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: flagData)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name < rhs.name
    }

    struct HeadingData: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let isoAlpha3: String
        let flag: Data
    }

    struct CurrencyData: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id: UUID
        let code: String
        let name: String
        let symbol: String
    }
}

class CountryModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var countries: [Country] = []

    init() {
        self.countries = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
//        let data = self.countries
//        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
}
```

**Computed Property to decode the clientFlag**

```
extension ClientEntity {
    var showFlag: Image {
        let str = clientFlag ?? Data()
        if str.isEmpty {
            let flagImage = Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            return flagImage
        } else {
            let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: str) ?? Data()
            guard let flagImage = UIImage.init(data: dataDecoded) else { return Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
            return Image(uiImage: flagImage)
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreData

class ClientViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var clientName = ""
    @Published var clientAddress1 = ""
    @Published var clientAddress2 = ""
    @Published var clientPhoneNumber = ""
    @Published var clientHostCountry = ""
    @Published var clientFlag: Data?
    @Published var clientIndustry = ""
    @Published var clientLogo: Data?
    @Published var clientComments = ""
    @Published var clientExisting = false
    @Published var clientWebSite: URL?
    @Published var clientUpdated: Date = Date()
    @Published var clientCreated: Date = Date()
    @Published var clientItem: ClientEntity!
    @Published var selectedContact: [ContactEntity] = []
    
    func addClient(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if clientItem == nil {
            let client = ClientEntity(context: context)
            client.clientName = clientName
            client.clientAddress1 = clientAddress1
            client.clientAddress2 = clientAddress2
            client.clientPhoneNumber = clientPhoneNumber
            print("clientVM \(clientHostCountry)")
            client.clientHostCountry = clientHostCountry
            client.clientFlag = clientFlag
            client.clientIndustry = clientIndustry
            // client.clientLogo = clientLogo
            client.clientComments = clientComments
            client.clientExisting = clientExisting
            // client.clientWebSite = clientWebSite
            client.clientUpdated = clientUpdated
            client.clientCreated = clientCreated
            print("Selected Contact: \(selectedContact.description)")
            let uniqueContact = Set(selectedContact)
            for contact in uniqueContact {
                client.addToContacts(contact)
            }
        } else {
            clientItem.clientName = clientName
            clientItem.clientAddress1 = clientAddress1
            clientItem.clientAddress2 = clientAddress2
            clientItem.clientPhoneNumber = clientPhoneNumber
            clientItem.clientHostCountry = clientHostCountry
            clientItem.clientFlag = clientFlag
            clientItem.clientIndustry = clientIndustry
            // clientItem.clientLogo = clientLogo
            clientItem.clientComments = clientComments
            clientItem.clientExisting = clientExisting
            // clientItem.clientWebSite = clientWebSite
            clientItem.clientUpdated = clientUpdated
            clientItem.clientCreated = clientCreated
            print("Selected Contact: \(selectedContact.description)")
            let uniqueContact = Set(selectedContact)
            for contact in uniqueContact {
                clientItem.addToContacts(contact)
            }
        }
        save(context: context)
        clientName = ""
        clientAddress1 = ""
        clientAddress2 = ""
        clientPhoneNumber = ""
        clientHostCountry = ""
        clientFlag = Data()
        clientIndustry = ""
        // clientLogo = Data()
        clientComments = ""
        clientExisting = false
        //        clientWebSite = URL(string: "")!
        clientUpdated = Date()
        clientCreated = Date()
        
    }
    
    func editClient(client: ClientEntity) {
        clientItem = client
    }
    
    func delete(client: ClientEntity, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context.delete(client)
        save(context: context)
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func isExisting(client: ClientEntity, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        client.clientExisting.toggle()
        save(context: context)
    }
}
```

I tried adding the .jpeg and .png parameters as well as the reverse of the successful Picker code.  No luck.

**New Issue**
The program crashes with Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2 (1) error (green background?) at the .tag(country as Country) in the Picker. Hovering over the 'country' property shows that it contains the 1st country in the JSON file. The Variables window shows:

country B2Bv5.Country
id  Foundation.UUID
uuid    (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)
name    String
_guts   _StringGuts
_object _StringObject
_countAndFlagsBits  UInt64  13835058055282163723
_object Builtin.BridgeObject    0x4000600001ef0ec0
isoAlpha3   String
_guts   _StringGuts
_object _StringObject
_countAndFlagsBits  UInt64  4671041
_object NSTaggedPointerString   "RCp1xmeaxi"    0xe300000000000000
flag    String? some
_guts   _StringGuts
_object _StringObject
_countAndFlagsBits  UInt64  13835058055282165492
_object Builtin.BridgeObject    0x4000000128065000

**CountryViewModel**

```
import SwiftUI
```

struct Country: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable, Hashable {

```
let id = UUID() // New
let name: String
let isoAlpha3: String
let flag: String?
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, isoAlpha3, flag
}

var flagImage: UIImage? {
        if let flagString = flag,
           let data = flagString.data(using: .utf8),
           let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data),
           let image = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
            return image
        } else {
            let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle")
            return img == nil ? UIImage() : img!
        }
    }

static func == (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
    lhs.name == rhs.name
}

static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
    lhs.name < rhs.name
}

struct HeadingData: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: String
}

struct CurrencyData: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
}
```

}

class CountryModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var countries: [Country] = []

```
init() {
    self.countries = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
}
```

}

**Picker extension**

```
var hostCountry: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Picker(selection: $clientVM.clientHostCountry,
               label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(countryVM.countries) { country in
                VStack {
                    Text(country.name)
                    Image(uiImage: country.flagImage!)
                }.tag(country as Country)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            .padding()
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
```

**extension ClientEntity**

```
extension ClientEntity {
var showName: String {
    return clientName ?? "Undefined"
}
```

}

```
extension ClientEntity {
var showExisting: String {
    if clientExisting {
        return " Client"
    } else {
        return "New Logo"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this simple approach, to display the `Image` of the flag, works for me:

As can be seen in the json data, `flag` is a `String`.
So make sure you declare `let flag: String?` in your `struct Country`, so you can decode the json in your `CountryModel`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let flag = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAIAAAAVyRqTAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoyRDFBRDI0NTE3NkYxMUUyODY3Q0FBOTFCQzlGNjlDRiIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDoyRDFBRDI0NjE3NkYxMUUyODY3Q0FBOTFCQzlGNjlDRiI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjdERDBDNDA4MTc1MzExRTI4NjdDQUE5MUJDOUY2OUNGIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjJEMUFEMjQ0MTc2RjExRTI4NjdDQUE5MUJDOUY2OUNGIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+GPq/agAAAiRJREFUeNrEVb9rFEEUfm9m9nb3bhNz50UMClopRAsFrUURW1tBrSzsLPwfbPwDbGz8F8QiIkLAKiCkUIKiGBEFwXAhd7fZH7Mz83zZtbC4TdyF4LDF8N7ON9/73jczuN4/A4czBBzaqIUmAA+Q0wjQRzkUCsv4USEHKKs4/0DtWOdAgxLxrUk+mqyHIkLx2eg1k1gA3kwDtYFeFOqVnj5NRwXQip7eGG9+svlPV1wff3mejwuiZ9n2i3zCRWANAta1kaFX9OS1jkdkHdGyCt6blMmel8E3p1OgY6iueL2b/pEtZ5qx5kRCLIhMyK4WMQFt2HzdpEzypZ5OnOVUSoT1gqi6BOvA7ZoDUan5JB3BXxPeOALBahigxloLQO4SFy5hBjMOpuA0zc4ebL4OYExuZl0dxNiRh63MZ4jYXjzJiG77/cuqW8UvqvBO0Ge+jjsplKHmgrCIIeICyke9pXPKZ+kvqPCS1+X6T4vO42iJN/YB22jNIo6cYWN9dfqdya560TxKruKaF32w2abVW2VWtNCa6fRQnpTeD1vcD4anZOdNEa8VCZN9EA6/2+KE9Ob3dUit+XbJHRfqXjBgTZjYhk3nUDAQN/CsDJbDYIfcbvlhU+hqQUpuSo6tcstfYMp8q9z1+7+cyfZMuUe4zZGp/GfLxRm4bbIPu4scYbIJOO6EO+hSVf9y8zLQmGxUKrNDRu7HtSH0n+NHrpr8/1fmtwADAEjB+xzEjgF0AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"

    @State var img = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: img)
        .onAppear {
            if let data = flag.data(using: .utf8),
               let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data),
               let image = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
                img = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1

In your model struct `Country` you may want to use the following code:

```
struct Country: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let isoAlpha3: String
    let flag: String?   // <--- here
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, isoAlpha3, flag
    }
    
    // --- here
    var flagImage: UIImage? {
        if let flagString = flag,
           let data = flagString.data(using: .utf8),
           let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data),
           let image = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
            return image
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    //....
}
```

Once you have your image as `Data`, you can use that to store it in your `clientFlag` in your `ClientEntity` and your `ClientViewModel` things.

EDIT-2:

In your `Picker`,
instead of using this `if let data = country.flag!.data(using: .utf8),...etc`
trying to again decode the flag,
why not use the `country.flagImage`, this is what you have it for. Modify `struct Country` with:

```
var flagImage: UIImage {
    if let flagString = flag,
       let data = flagString.data(using: .utf8),
       let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data),
       let image = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
        return image
    } else {
        let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle")
        return img == nil ? UIImage() : img!
    }
}
```

and in the `Picker` use:

```
    VStack {
        Text(country.name)
        Image(uiImage: country.flagImage)
    }
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for decoding the JSON flag string. My next step is to add the JSON flag string to the ClientEntity. The user gets to choose the country from a Picker that displays the country name and the flag. The code below is part of an extension, but generates a "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression..." error on the VStack.

Comment: Code too long for comment, so split:

Comment: 'VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Picker(selection: $clientVM.clientHostCountry,
                           label: Text("")) {
                        ForEach(countryVM.countries) { country in
                            VStack {
                                Text(country.name)
                                if let data = country.flag!.data(using: .utf8),
                                   let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: data),
                                   let image = UIImage(data: decodedData) {
                                    let img = image {'

Comment: 'return Image(uiImage: img) }
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                }
                            }.tag(country as Country?)
                        }
                    }
                           .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                           .padding()
                           .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        }.padding(.horizontal)'

Comment: updated my answer with some more code example.

Comment: Most grateful for your input. I have edited the original to show relevant code around the Thread crash.

Comment: Observations: you should not have `Image` in your `extension ClientEntity {...}`, 
`Image` is for use in a View, use `UIImage` like in the `struct Country`.
Your new `struct Country`  should have  `var flagImage: UIImage`, **not optional**.
 In the `Picker` you had `.tag(country as Country?)` now you have `.tag(country as Country)`, 
you have to pay attention to the details. In your `class ClientViewModel` all the `var client...` should be in 
a `struct`. Currently there are too many missing parts to debug your code.

Comment: Your patience is appreciated. I only have 2 extension ClientEntity {...}, but none containing Image. Code added above.

Answer (score 0):

Your flag image string `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAIAAAAVyRqTAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw` is almost base64, but not quite - it's missing the padding characters at the end that `Data(base64encoded:)` needs.

You can easily add them like this:

```
let str = "iVBOR...AADw" // your clientFlag string from JSON
let pad = String(repeating: "=", count: 4 - (str.count % 4))
let data = Data(base64Encoded: str + pad)
```

Comment: The last line throws error: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Data? and String'.  Should I change the Attribute Type in the ClientEntity to  a String, thereby storing the raw JSON value?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. What I meant was to use the `clientFlag` String you get from your JSON.